# Error synchronizing cache state: connection refused for conversion webhook

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks, argocd

I am using ArgoCD to update my applications, at some point I started getting an error like:

```
error synchronizing cache state : failed to sync cluster https://10.233.0.1:443: failed to load initial state of resource
TestSuite.tests.testkube.io: conversion webhook for tests.testkube.io/v2, Kind=TestSuite failed: 
Post "https://testkube-operator-webhook-service.testkube.svc:443/convert?timeout=30s": dial tcp 10.233.34.99:443: connect: connection refused
```

I get the same error when running the `kubectl -n testkube get TestSuite` command.
I removed the testkube validation/mutation hooks but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the finally I just remove my crd:

```
kubectl delete crd testsuites.tests.testkube.io
```